# session expires when use mod_proxy in apache2

Tags: apache, perl

I am trying to redirect the particular url from one server to another server. Both the places I am using the apache2 server.

I am getting the session expired error. Could you please guide me to resolve this issue. Please find the code as follows,

```
  SSLEngine On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  -----------
  -----------


  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /test/ https://testserver1.net/test/
  ProxyPassReverse /test/ https://testserver1.net/test/
  ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain testserver.net testserver1.net
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /test https://testserver1.net/test
```